# Why does Android OS data usage not count?

Tags: mobile-data, data-monitoring, lineageos, 7.1-nougat, background-data

I have noticed that "Android OS" consumes a lot of data on my phone (LineageOS 14.1; Samsung Galaxy SIII GT-I9300; rooted). However, this data seems not to count for the overall data usage. As you can see in the picture below, Android OS consumed 36.72 MB so far. But that is more than the total data usage at the top (28.11 MB). This determined total data usage is the same as my provider says. Is there a particular reason why the data usage of Android OS does not count? Has it something to do with Nougat or even LineageOS?

[image: Android OS consumes data which does not count]

---

On the other hand, My Data Manager, for example, seems to take Android OS into account:

[image: My Data Manager takes Android OS into account]

Does someone know the reason for this issue or does somebody have an assumption at least?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, **Android OS** (sometimes called **OS + others**) is not actually a real application to say. Basing this on one data application I've used it is explained;

> It is a "catch all" pseudo-application accounting for the difference
>   between **global usage** (displayed in the main screen) and the **sum of all
>   installed applications usages**.

- Initially it will be **equal to global usage**, but discrepancies can easily be noted in case when an application which previously had access to data connectivity is uninstalled.
- On the other hand, the value can stay as a very small value (few MBs) perhaps if the applications that occasionally use data are not affected (remain intact).
- The other reason, I can think of is, data used in some minor updates (to Android itself), connectivity checks etc  can be assigned to Android OS in data usage counter such that there is always a reading for such in data counters.

I don't think this has something to do with Lineage OS or Nougat but just a conventional way for counting data usage accross apps (regardless they were uninstalled in that particular usage period)